# using sigsetjmp and siglongjmp functions correctly

Tags: c, signals

I'm using some OLD C code (circa early 90's).  There are leaks in the windowing library in use that causes it leak memory over time.  To resolve this leak I have to close the window and re-create it which frees up the parsing structures.  Vendor is long since dead...

So, I keep a count of the number of window refreshes and when I reach a set threshold, siglongjmp back to a saved state location.  I used sigsetjmp(jmp_Addr, 1) to have it
save the signals in effect when the jmp occurs.

The issue occuring is the signal state appears pooched as sometimes the code in the library goes ape and fails on an error.  This typically is a signal interrupted the library code.

In the refresh function (signal handler) that is invoked when the signal is received, it dispatches to call the windowing library to rebuild the screen with new info.  I believe what is occuring is the signal state is not what I THINK it should be when the siglongjmp is being done and a new signal arrives and dispatches to the signal handler and things
go boom.

thought...?

Comment: Are you attempting to save the signal state at the time `sigsetjmp` is called, or at the time `siglongjmp` is called?

Comment: Yes, I pass 1 as the second arg to sigsetjmp(jmp_Addr, 1);

the call to siglongjmp is being made in the signal handler function which I'm not sure if that is a good thing to be doing.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: Do you want to save the current signal state at the time sigsetjmp is called, or the current signal state at the time siglongjmp is called?

Comment: My understanding of how sigsetjmp works is that it saves a copy of the signal mask that was in effect when it is called.  This is what I'm expecting to be the case.  This assuming you pass the second arg to it of 1.

Comment: ok, I was under the impression you wanted the opposite.

Comment: I'm trying to test how the process will behave under load when many lines are in use and sending signal updates to this process.  My test is using a script that sends the signal every 1/10th of a second....  heavy load for sure...  Failing this I'd have to configure 60 or so lines (serial) and in a limited lab space...not really doable.

Comment: Why are you using signals to trigger the rebuild of the window? Or, signals at all? Your code, I presume, calls the lib, but gets control back. You can check the counter in your code and do a window close and reopen without signals or longjmps. Just put all window creation code in a new function and call that when the counter overflows. `setjmp/longjmp` will only save some register state. So, you have to keep the other variables anyway. What am I missing? Or, if you have the lib source, you could _debug_ it ;-)

Comment: There are N line drivers (each of which are separate processes) that communicate with this process.  State information relating what the line mode is (read/write/open, etc.) is stored in shared memory.  Each line driver has to somehow send a notification to the display program to have it update the status.

Comment: One question Craig, when you say above "calls the lib"...which lib are you referring to?  The windowing library in use is from 1990, a pre-cursor to X windows.  It has a similar event loop for obtaining mouse movements and keyboard input and the ability to have it call a function when idle, which is what I'm using.  It's here that I do the check for refreshing the display.   The trigger signal is unblocked upon entry to this function and blocked again on exit.

Comment: if the signals continues to be problematic, I could use a new boolean in shared memory per line I guess that would get set true when an update has been done.  the refresh function would check this and toggle it off when the newly updated data has been pushed the X display.

Comment: that'll learn me for trying to make 35 yr old code more stable...

Comment: the new stuff will be SOOOOOO much better...honest dad!